# Is it possible to just edit text in a obfuscated .net dll

Tags: c#, dll, obfuscation

I'm using an old dll that hasn't been updated since 2008. It recently stopped working.

I decompiled and noticed that it's obfuscated and I noticed that I just need to change a string value. Can I use something hexedit or something to make the change keeping the DLL intacted? I dont want to try and download the entire source, I just want to make my string change.

Comment: For the case where the assembly is a signed assembly, and you require it to be signed after the change, then no. That's not possible.

Comment: It stopped working because of a single string value? My goodness. Sounds like there was no need for an obfuscator, the original developers did quite a number on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program I used a while back called [Reflexil](http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/reflexil/) which served this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I am doing research on Reflexil right now. It looks promising, if this works I'll mark you answer.

Comment: You also should take a look at Dotnet IL Editor.